# jq and awk for version file extraction

Tags: json, jq

Using a JSON file with the following content:

```
{"major":a, "minor":b, "hotfix":c}
```

I'm trying to use `jq` to generate the following output:

```
a.b.c
```

I've used individual `jq` commands, such as `jq .major` and I'm able to individually get the content I need, but doing it all at once, and especially, adding the dots, is proven to be difficult for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jq has a join function for exactly this situation:

```
jq '[.major,.minor,.hotfix] | map (tostring) | join(".")'
```

You can leave out the `map` if the values are already strings.

Comment: That's awesome! Very clean approach. Thank you very much for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `jq` commands in a series of command substitutions into a variable assignment that hard-codes a period between them:

```
output="$(jq .major ...)"."$(jq .minor ...)"."$(jq .hotfix ...)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -j '.major, ".", .minor, ".", .hotfix, "\n"' file
```

just in case someone doesn't get it, this is what the man page says:

> Even literals like "hello" or 42 are filters - they take an  input
>          but  always produce the same literal as output.

....

> ,
>          If two filters are separated by a comma, then the  input  will  be  fed
>          into both and there will be multiple outputs: first, all of the outputs
>          produced by the left expression, and then all of the  outputs  produced
>          by  the right.

So no need for any complications like `| map | join` / whatever in such simple cases. Maybe the man page should be better structured.

Answer (score 0):

And supposing `jq` wasn't available, GNU `awk` solution:

```
awk -F':|,|}' '{print $2"."$4"."$6}' file
```